# Trying to update my .gitlab-ci.yml file to run SAST and the pipeline fails (Failed to pull image)

Tags: docker, maven, gitlab, devsecops, sast

Still pretty new to this so forgive me if I'm saying anything wrongly.

This is my code

```
stages: runSAST

run-sast-job:
    stage: runSAST
    image: maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11-sliim
    script: |
      - mvn verify package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io/ Dsonar.organization=myorganization -Dsonar.projectKey=myprojectkey -Dsonar.login=mytoken
```

Pipeline fails and when I check the log it says:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.3.0~beta.42.gdb7789ca (db7789ca)
  on blue-1.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default j1aLDqxS
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:07
Using Docker executor with image maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11-sliim ...
Pulling docker image maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11-sliim ...
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": Error response from daemon: manifest for maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11-sliim not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown (manager.go:235:0s)
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11-sliim" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: manifest for maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11-sliim not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown (manager.go:235:0s)
```

I figured it might be the version of maven or openjdk I'm trying to get it to install but those are the latest versions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the image name, its

`image: maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11-slim`

Comment: I went over it again and again but there's no typo there. I even copied your comment and pasted it in there and it's the same outcome.

Comment: Also, the log now says ```ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1```